# importing multiple .csv files to one data set in Rstudio from multiple directories

Tags: r, csv, import

I'm doing a project and I have to import a ton of .csv files into Rstudio. The files correspond to dates. Each date has a directory filled with files from that day. To get all the data for one day I'v been using:

```
im = list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
my-data = lapply(im, read_csv)
```

The problem is I have hundreds of days worth of files so hundreds of directories to go through.  Is there a way to pull all the files from all the directories at once into the same data table? Bonus if it can include the date (title of the directory it's in) in the data table. Also we use tidyverse and tibbles if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the directories are in one root directory, try `list.files(recursive = TRUE)`, which will search subdirectories as well. Additionally, look at the `purrr` trick of `set_names()` and `imap`, which iterates over both contents and names of an object, would let you bring the filenames in as a column. Something like the following. Note that you'll have to use some string tools to get just the date from the end of the `filepaths`.

```
library(tidyverse)
all_files <- "path/to/root/folder" %>%
    list.files(pattern = "csv", "recursive = TRUE", full.names = "TRUE") %>%
    set_names() %>%
    imap_dfr(~ bind_cols(read_csv(.x), filepath = .y))
```

Comment: The dates are the names of the subdirectories, could I use include.dirs to add them to the table?

Comment: Test the above code on a sample and see what it does. `full.names = TRUE` means that it will get the entire path of the file, so the `filepath` variable will include filenames as well as the subdirectory names. Use `str_extract` and regular expressions to pull out the date from that.

Comment: Ok so I ran `list.file(pattern = ".csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)` and now I have a list of the files in the format "date/filename.csv" and I want to apply the date in the file name to every item in the file in the data set.

Comment: so did you try the second part?? it should take "date/filename.csv" and add it as a column called `filepath` to each imported csv, then row-bind them together into one big one.

Comment: Yeah I got `Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 2 must be length 1, not 83`

Comment: Ok, then read up on each of the literally three functions there. Sounds like the bind_cols isn't working as planned. what if you do `imap_dfr(~ bind_cols(read_csv(.x)))`? what about `imap_dfr(~ tibble(filepath = .y))`? without any sample data this is impossible to troubleshoot, the tools to figure it out are there.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem - below solution worked for me :-)

```
require(tidyverse)

path <- "/my/root/"

read_plus <- function(flnm) {
  read_csv(flnm) %>% 
    mutate(filename = flnm)
}

my_data <-
  list.files(path, pattern = "*.csv", 
             recursive = T,
             full.names = T) %>% 
  map_df(~read_plus(.))
```